# set value for a field after the form is rendered in processForm

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to set a userID while a form is processed in `processForm`, located in `actions.class.php`. The problem is, I have unset the userID field and somehow I can't set a value for that. I've searched but I couldn't find anything useful.

I don't want to set the value in a hidden field or something like this, since the userID isn't the only value I want to set. Some values are based on the form request itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change fields right after the binding - for example this is in my `processForm` method

```
$form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
if ($form->isValid())
{
  $model = $form->save();
  $model->setField(value);
  $model->save();
}
```

Ensure you call the save() method else the changes wont be visible